# Add native zoom in/out functionality and other camera native features with WebRTC on android

Tags: android, webrtc, android-camera, arcore

I have a working WebRTC video call system which is able to stream audio and video.
The drawback of using WebRTC video capturer class is that it takes control of your camera therefore you cannot use your camera's native features such as zoom in/out, flash/torch or any such feature.

Once the Video capturer has acquired the camera, no other processes can use the camera just like microphone. Only one process can take hold of camera at a time.

The VideoCapturer class only provides a function to switch between cameras. That's it!
I'm using Google webrtc dependency.